# php cookie and or set cookie issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

sorry for my english, i have an unknown issue on my website:

i try to save a cart in a cookie:

`var_dump` of the cookie before saving :

Code:

```
array (size=3)
'name' => string 'cart'
'value' => string '[{"id":"13991","id_prod":"18176","qty":1,"gravure":"","options_infos":[],"cadeau":0},{"id":"13983","id_prod":"18168","qty":1,"gravure":"","options_infos":[],"cadeau":0},{"id":"13987","id_prod":"18172","qty":1,"gravure":"","options_infos":[],"cadeau":0},{"id":"279543","id_prod":"29990","qty":1,"gravure":"","options_infos":[],"cadeau":0},{"id":"279554","id_prod":"30001","qty":1,"gravure":"","options_infos":[],"cadeau":0},{"id":"279539","id_prod":"29986","qty":1,"grav ure":"","options_infos":[],"cadeau":0},{"id'... (length=3301)
'expire' => int 2592000
```

this php function is triggered on my page to update the cookie cart,
this is what is blocking when i have more than approx  20 items on my cart

PHP Code:

```
public function refreshCookie() {
$items = array();
if (parent::contents()) {
foreach (parent::contents() as $key => $value) {

$prod = new stdClass();

$prod->id = $value['id'];
$prod->id_prod = $value['id_prod'];
$prod->qty = $value['qty'];

if (isset($value['gravure'])){
$prod->gravure = $value['gravure'];
} 
if (isset($value['options_infos'])){
$prod->options_infos = $value['options_infos'];
}
$prod->cadeau = $value['cadeau'];
$items[] = $prod;
}
}

$cookie = array(
'name' => 'cart',
'value' => json_encode($items),
'expire' => $this->CI->config->item('cookie_panier_lifetime')
);
$this->CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
}
```

this work fine in my local machine but not online when i have more than 20 items
it work, if i remove the `set_cookie` line (`$this->CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);`)
also note that if i use the php `setcookie` it is the same, so it is not really a codeigniter issue :/

i don't understand, any help would be appreciated
regards

Comment: Don't store all that in a cookie. There are cookie limits for a reason. Put all the cart into a server-side database, and only the cookie should reference the cart items by key (with some more robust security and access tokens as well in the mix).

Comment: The cookie size is generally limited to about 4KiB so if that's about the max size of your cart then that's probably why.

Comment: hello, this cookie is just used to save the cart and load it if the user come back after the session is closed
i don't understand why i have no limiation on my local machine (tested +100 items)
and only 20 on my server

Answer (score 0):

Size of the cookie may be the problem.

From [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/163539)

> **LimitRequestLine**
>   This directive sets the number of bytes that will be allowed on the HTTP request-line.
>   The LimitRequestLine directive allows the server administrator to reduce or increase the limit on the allowed size of a client's HTTP request-line. Since the request-line consists of the HTTP method, URI, and protocol version, the LimitRequestLine directive places a restriction on the length of a request-URI allowed for a request on the server. A server needs this value to be large enough to hold any of its resource names, including any information that might be passed in the query part of a GET request.
>   This directive gives the server administrator greater control over abnormal client request behavior, which may be useful for avoiding some forms of denial-of-service attacks.

Contacting the service provider may be helpful.